# C# database using oledb

Tags: c#

I have 3 table

1st one called member
Which consist of columns
1.MemberID 
2.MemberName
3.Address

2nd table called Movies
Consist of columns 
1.DVDnumber
2.MovieTitle
3.MovieType

3rd table Rental
1.DVDnumber
2.MemberID

A) should search for details of member
B) if the member has borrowed  a DVD should display DVD movieTitle and movie type

That is what I've done so far

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SWELIHLE\Desktop\test 2\JimmyJones.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "Select * from Member where MemberID =  '" + txtID.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            txtName.Text = reader["MemberName"].ToString();
            txtAdd.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();

        command.CommandText = "Select DVDnumber from Rental where MemberID =  '" + txtID.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
         while(rd.Read())
         {

             data.Text = rd["DVDnumber"].ToString(); 
         }

         rd.Close();
         command.CommandText = "select M.MemberName, M.Address, Mo.MovieTitle, Mo.MovieType, FROM Member M LEFT OUTER JOIN Rental R ON M.MemberID = R.MemberID LEFT OUTER JOIN Movie Mo ON Mo.DVDnumber = R.DVDnumber";
         OleDbDataReader raed = command.ExecuteReader();
         while (raed.Read())
         {

             txtMovieT.Text = raed["MovieTitle"].ToString();
         }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what are we suppose to do here?

Comment: Should search for  for member by entering memberID on textfield  and check If the member exist ... if the member exist it should also check if the user has borrowed a DVD  if the user borrowed the dvd it should display dvd  details  from movie table

Comment: I did my work BT  I'm struggling .. do u think I would be here if I was not struggle

Comment: Well, why don't you show what you've done maybe it'll be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a SQL Query for fetching the data you want. Here it goes:

```
SELECT M.Name, M.Address, Mo.MovieTitle, Mo.MovieType, 
FROM Member M
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rental R ON M.MemberID = R.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Movie Mo ON Mo.DVDnumber = R.DVDnumber
```

Please use correct tags while asking questions along with giving relevant explanation of the task you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
string mID = txtID.Text;

OleDbCommand command.CommandText = 
"SELECT m.* FROM Member m, Rental r WHERE 
    m.MemberID = r.MemberID AND 
    m.MemberID = '" + mID + "'";

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    // member found
    txtName.Text = reader["MemberName"].ToString();
    txtAdd.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();

    // query movies
    command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT mo.* FROM Member m, Movies mo, Rental r WHERE 
        m.MemberID = r.MemberID AND 
        r.DVDnumber = mo.DVDnumber AND 
        m.MemberID = '" + mID + "'";

    raeder = command.ExecuteReader();
    string movies;
    while (raeder.Read())
    {
        // multiple rentals possible?!
        movies += raeder["MovieTitle"].ToString() + '\n';
    }
    txtMovieT.Text = movies;
}
```

Comment: Was this useful for you? Would be very kind if you rate my answer